# Filter for _id in should request in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to filter for documents for certain _ids in a should request. This is what I have tried:

```
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "_id": "abc"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "def"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Error Message:

> {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[-Qaf9MhvRhasY5h92lDrXg][appsearch][0]: SearchParseException[[appsearch][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is to add:

```
{"term":{"_id":"abc"}}
```